# What are the escape characters needed for a string in SSH

Tags: string, escaping, sh

I've been trying to find a comprehensive list of all the characters I need to escape in a given string.

I have 5000 files on a server, each with a specific string of text in them like so:

```
ksk$/'sx"sa w"\223~$1@@  -;.zmc.n/,865@#$%^&*()_+!
```

Now, I want to search for that string and remove it in each of those 5000 files.

So, which characters need to be escaped properly and how do I escape each of them?

I know I have to use \ to escape a forward slash. But what about quotations? What about dollar signs? What about space characters? What other characters need to be escaped and how?

Anyone know where I can find a complete list?

Example ssh command:

```
find /mypath -type f -exec sed -i 's/ksk$/'sx"saw"\223~$1@@-;.zmc.n/,865@#$%^&*()_+! /g' {} \;
```

Comment: This is not about `ssh`. It's about the shell (likely `bash`, but could be something else) in which you run `ssh`, and which `ssh` runs on the remote side once the connection is established. The quoting/escaping rules can be different for different shells, and when you start throwing things like `sed`/`awk`/`grep`/`python`/`perl` into the equation, the rules vary even more...

Comment: Thanks, just trying to get a handle on this stuff.